# Database in project C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio, local-database

I made a project in my Visual Studio 2013-C#(Windows Form Application).
My project is a simple one, in order to get used to using databases.

I have done the following things:

1) I made a Database on MySql Server and created a table.

2) Then, I created a SqlDataAdapter and connected it to the DataBase and used it to fill data in a new DataTable.

3) I changed values in DataTable and the updated the Database with 
SqlDataAdapter.Update();

Everything works just fine when I am using a Database in MySql Server. But I need to work with a Database in my project, as I need this app to work on other pc's to, when only copying the project. Apparently, creating a local database in the project folder does not work, as the Database does not update.

Perhaps, my Database is disconnecting when my app starts?
Please, tell me a possible solution tot his problem, or how can I make a Database that works when moved to other PC's, from the project folder.

PS: Maybe it is a problem from my connection strings, but I do not think so, as I am creating the Database manually. Or maybe it is a problem because my app is in the project folder.

Comment: If every PC installation is using a local database then you will need MySQL server installed on the local PCs.  Part of your deployment will have to check the necessary dependencies and install the server/database as necessary.  Even if you connect to a database file via a file path you still need the database server on the PC to do the database 'stuff'.

Comment: @James Gaunt -The problem is that I have to do this project for a contest. So I need to send my project folder. They must have an SQL Server installed, but I can not know the path where they have teh server. So my question is, how can I make my local database so that their PC will use it when running my app?

Comment: And why if I create an Local Database in my project it is not working?

Comment: Just having a local database file doesn't achieve anything.  You need to access a running MySQL server via a connection string.  It really depends how much you 'know' about the local PC.  If you can connect to a running database server you can run an SQL script on it to create the database. But you need to know the connection string (including any necessary credentials) for an instance of SQL server that is running, if it's not running start it (by finding the .exe).  This will not simply work in every environment you drop the application into.

Comment: Really - this is 'bad idea' unless it's absolutely necessary.  I'd recommend either just working with local files (rather than a DB) provided you can do without the transactional operations.  Otherwise host a DB remotely and connect to it over the internet.

Comment: I don't know if MySQL has an equivalent or MySQL is a prerequisite to your situation, but you could be using SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx